# Kendo UI vs Application Craft

Tags: android, ios, frameworks, windows-phone

i want to create mobile apps for cross-mobile platforms. 
Two Frameworks are interesting for me.
Kendo UI vs Application Craft.

Important for me are supporting charts. I know, that both Frameworks are supporting this but which one is better?

Thanks & Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried both personally (not in professional projects) and I have find both very similar.

However, it was easier to find solutions to Kendo problems than to find the Application Craft. It seems like Kendo is more community supported in terms of forums.

With both I achieved the results I was looking for, but still it took me slightly more time to do it with application craft